# Software/tool for simple image stitching/mosaicking?

Tags: image-processing

I have several images (more specifically: map tiles), which overlap one another to some degree (not 100%). I would want to automatically mosaic or stitch them into a single, homogeneous image.

One way to achieve that certainly is using GIMP: Create an empty image that is at least as large as the result image you expect, manually insert the individual image/map tiles, manually align them.

I also now Hugin, but that doesn't do the job for me, as it is designed for perspective images and takes much too complicated models with plenty of distortions into account - whereas I really only need translations, not even rotations. And for sure no skewings etc.

Is there any Ubunto tool/software that would do what I need? In summary: Automatic matching (i.e. identification of tie points), estimation of transformation (2 parameters, i.e. translation in x and y direction) per image pair, resampling of images based on the estimated transformation. I don't even necessarily need radiomatric adjustment.